# Как найти источник ошибки "Missing connection or connectionString"?

Tags: база-данных, delphi, отладка, xdebug, radstudio

При запуске программы появляется ошибка

> Missing connection or connectionString

Пока, удалось выяснить, что ошибка появляться после  `Application.CreateForm(TGuestForm, GuestForm);` Но в `OnCreate` никаких операций с БД нету.

Приложение падает в:

```
procedure DatabaseError(const Message: string; Component: TComponent = nil);
begin
  if Assigned(Component) and (Component.Name <> '') then
  begin
    if (csSubComponent in Component.ComponentStyle) and (Component.Owner <> nil) and
      (Component.Owner.Name <> '') then
      raise EDatabaseError.Create(Format('%s.%s: %s', [Component.Owner.Name, Component.Name, Message]))
    else
      raise EDatabaseError.Create(Format('%s: %s', [Component.Name, Message]))
  end
  else
    raise EDatabaseError.Create(Message);
end;
```

Comment: Причина ошибки в выставленном в Design Time свойства Active := True у  ADOQuery лежащим на форме, но у него прописано свойство Connection, и в чем причина пока не понятно, в дизайнере ошибок нет.

Comment: дак со строкой подключения то что у коннекшена?

Comment: Так в design time же без ошибок переключение свойства Active работает, значит нормально

Comment: там строка, или UDL?

Comment: Сам Connection где находится. Если в датамодуле, то посмотрите последовательность создания форм. Дата модуль должен создаваться первым. И еще попробуйте в DesignTime у Connection свойство Active или Connected поставить false и запустите программу

Comment: У Connection свойство Active или Connected поставить false, А в главной форме по событию OnCreate или OnShow переключайте в True